# Error on my first class when trying to display

Tags: c++

I'm building a class that will create a vehicle's characteristics and I'm having some difficulties when trying to display autovehicle a1 on the console. I get an error which I cannot explain. Please help, if possible

```
   #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Autovehicle {
private:
    //registry number
    char * car_registration_number;
    char engine;
    int engine_cc;
    int avg_consumption;
    int avg_speed;
    int avg_consumption_urban;
    int avg_speed_urban;
    int max_speed;
    static int number_of_autovehicles;
public:
    //getters
    char * get_car_registration_number() {
        return this->car_registration_number;
    }

    char get_engine()
    {
        return this->engine;
    }

    int get_engine_cc() {
        return this->engine_cc;
    }
    int get_avg_consumption() {
        return this->avg_consumption;
    }
    int get_avg_speed() {
        return this->avg_speed;
    }
    int get_avg_consumption_urban() {
        return this->avg_consumption_urban;
    }
    int get_avg_speed_urban() {
        return this->avg_speed_urban;
    }
    int get_max_speed() {
        return this->max_speed;
    }
    static int get_number_of_cars() {
        return number_of_autovehicles;
    }
    //setters
    void set_car_registration_number(char *car_reg_nr) {
        this->car_registration_number = car_reg_nr;
    }
    void set_engine(char eng) {
        this->engine = eng;
    }
    void set_engine_cc(int eng_cc) {
        this->engine_cc = eng_cc;
    }
    void set_avg_consumption(int avg_cons) {
        this->avg_consumption = avg_cons;
    }
    void set_avg_speed(int avg_spd) {
        if (this->avg_speed > avg_spd)
            cout << endl << "You should probably slow down";
        this->avg_speed = avg_spd;
    }
    void set_avg_consumption_urban(int avg_cons_urb) {
        this->avg_consumption_urban = avg_cons_urb;
    }
    void set_avg_speed_urban(int avg_spd_urb) {
        if (this->avg_speed_urban > avg_spd_urb)
            cout << endl << "You should probably slow down";
        this->avg_speed_urban = avg_spd_urb;
    }
    void set_max_speed(int max_spd) {
        this->max_speed = max_spd;
    }
    //default constructor
    Autovehicle(){
        number_of_autovehicles++;
        this->car_registration_number = new char[strlen("There are no autovehicles") + 1];
        strcpy(this->car_registration_number, "There are no autovehicles");
        this->engine = NULL;
        this->engine_cc = 0;
        this->avg_consumption = 0;
        this->avg_speed = 0;
        this->avg_consumption_urban = 0;
        this->avg_speed_urban = 0;
        this->max_speed = 0;

    }
    //constructor
    Autovehicle(char* car_reg_nr, char eng, int eng_cc, int avg_cons, int avg_spd, int avg_cons_urb, int avg_spd_urb, int max_spd){
        number_of_autovehicles++;
        this->car_registration_number = new char[strlen(car_reg_nr) + 1];
        strcpy(this->car_registration_number, car_reg_nr);
        this->engine = eng;
        this->engine_cc = eng_cc;
        this->avg_consumption = avg_cons;
        this->avg_speed = avg_spd;
        this->avg_consumption_urban = avg_cons_urb;
        this->avg_speed_urban = avg_spd_urb;
        this->max_speed = max_spd;
    }
    //destructor
    ~Autovehicle() {
        delete[]this->car_registration_number;
        number_of_autovehicles--;
    }

};
```

This is where the void main, and the problem starts:

```
void main() {
    Autovehicle a1( "Engniasd", "gasoline", 1980, 11, 50, 8, 100) {
        cout<<"registration number: "<< this->car_registration_number;
        cout << "engine: " << this->engine;
        cout << "engine cc:" << this->engine_cc;
        cout << "consumption: " << this->avg_consumption;
        cout << "avg speed: " << this->avg_speed;
        cout << "urban consumption: " << this->avg_consumption_urban;
        cout << "urban speed " << this->avg_speed_urban;

    }
}
```

The problem that I'm getting is "No instance of constructor matches the argument list" when trying to display Autovehicle a1(Engniasd, the first term)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the registration number to your car and the number of vehicles:

Autovehicle a1(**"REG12345"**, "gasoline", 1980, 11, 50, 8, 100, 50, **3**).

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor defines `eng` as a `char`, but you're passing it `"gasoline"` which is a `const char*`.

Also, storing the car registration number as a `char*`. Make your life easier and use a `std::string` instead. That way you, and your class users, don't need to worry about managing the lifetime of the pointer.

And, in `main` you've declared a variable called `a1` but it looks like you are trying to call methods on it using `this`. You need to call against the instance variable:

```
cout << "engine: " << a1.engine;
```

You also need to terminate the `a1` declaration with a semicolon and don't need the braces, eg:

```
Autovehicle a1( "Engniasd", "gasoline", 1980, 11, 50, 8, 100); 
cout << "registration number: "<< a1.car_registration_number;
```

Comment: I changed all that and it solves the error but now after the parenthesis the { after it says it is expecting a ";"

Comment: @OctavianCatusanu - I've updated the answer. If you're having trouble understanding some of these errors then you're going to struggle with C++ as you progress with it.

Answer (score 0):

At school atm and unable to get a good look at this, but look at your constructor, you have a char instead of a char ptr for your 2nd argument. you can't implicitly convert char to const char*, you can char* -> const char*, so change your 2nd argument to a char*. Also, change void main() to int main(), main is supposed to be an int (ansi standard), and many compilers might not accept you using void main().

Comment: I made both of them char *, but I still have the same error

Comment: Note that you're missing an argument as well in your constructor. It's setup to look for 8 arguments, you're only giving it 7 (missing an int of course).

Comment: When I try to put another int in i get to the first error again

Comment: Okay, so how many arguments do you have in autovehicle a1 (the one declared in void main(), which should be int main() b/c that's the standard).

Comment: I have 8 at the moment, I modified the code with what mr. Yuriy Orlov posted

Comment: Now it shows what I want but I get a "Debug Assertion Failed!" error

Comment: What does the window error say? what's the expression error, and are you still using this-> instead of a1. (since you said you used what Mr. Yurli posted, and this-> is incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems.

Can you explain why car_registration_number and engine have different types?

If you can answer this one for yourself, you can fix one of your issues.

Also you should separate the class declaration from the implementation and make sure that you initialize all the variables. Including the static one.

Comment: I made both of them char *, but I still have the same error

Answer (score 0):

Problems in calling constructor

```
Autovehicle(char* , char , int, int, int, int, int, int)
```

the second parameter is char, but you pass char*, also constructor have 6 int parameters, but you pass only five in main. And you cannot print values of object in your way. Create function in you class

```
void print()
{
    cout<<"registration number: "<< this->car_registration_number;
    cout << "engine: " << this->engine;
    cout << "engine cc:" << this->engine_cc;
    cout << "consumption: " << this->avg_consumption;
    cout << "avg speed: " << this->avg_speed;
    cout << "urban consumption: " << this->avg_consumption_urban;
    cout << "urban speed " << this->avg_speed_urban;
}
```

and call it in main() as

```
Autovehicle a1( "Engniasd", "gasoline", 1980, 11, 50, 8, 100, 0);
a1.print();
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error, and it compiles and shows what I want, but now I get a "Debug assertion failed!" after it.

Comment: In which line you get a "Debug assertion failed!" ?

Comment: It says #141 but that's a different class which isn't yet in the main function.

Comment: Also if I remove the main I don't get this error so I don't think it's because of that class

Comment: public:, after which there's a comment